# OktaAuth authorization code flow in a React App

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, okta

I'm having trouble understanding how to use the okta-react library within my React App, to login using the authorization code (non pkce) grant type.

My setup as of right now is pretty simple:

```js
//App.tsx
const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth({
  issuer: 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/oauth2/default',
  clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/welcome-back',
  pkce: false,
  responseType: 'code',
  devMode: true
});

function App() {

  const history = useHistory();
  const restoreOriginalUri = async (_oktaAuth: any, originalUri: string) => {
    history.push(toRelativeUrl(originalUri || '/', window.location.origin));
  };

  return (
    <Security oktaAuth={oktaAuth} restoreOriginalUri={restoreOriginalUri}>
        <NavigationDispatcher/>
    </Security>
  );
}
```

And then in the NavigationDispatcher 2 simple routes (1 of them secured):

```js
        <>
            <Route path="/" component={HomepageView}/>
            <SecureRoute path="/secure-view" component={SecureView}/>
            <Route path='/welcome-back' component={LoginCallback}/>
        </>
```

So the configuration seems to work properly since when I try to access the SecureView it redirects me to my okta authorization server hosted ui where I log in. The problem is that I get redirected to the /welcome-back page after logging in (which I guess as it should?) but my 'authState' `const { authState } = useOktaAuth()` has everything undefined, as if the user never logged in.

I noticed that on the URL after getting redirected there is the 'code' parameter that then I could successfully use in postman to get the access token on the `/token` endpoint of my authorization server.

However I thought that the full flow would be handled by the okta-auth-js library. How can I implement the authorization code flow? And also, shouldn't the user be redirected to the original page he was trying to access, and not the default redirect uri?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use Auth Code flow (without PKCE), the Okta React library won't be able to complete the /token request to exchange the authorization code (the `code` parameter returned to your redirect_uri/callback route).

The React library, being client side, isn't designed/able to use Client ID:Client Secret auth for the /token request (its designed for PKCE auth, and [the readme notes that implicit flow and auth code flow with PKCE are the only supported flows](https://github.com/okta/okta-react#okta-react-sdk:%7E:text=This%20library%20currently%20supports%3A)) as it is unable to secure the secret. Your back-end would need to handle securing the secret and exchanging the code for tokens at the /token endpoint.